# cv2 wait input depending on previous input

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to `'do more some stuff'` after `'s'` is pressed. `'do more some stuff'` will be triggered with pressing any/specific key after recieving the `'s'` input. Because `'do more some stuff'` is dependent on `'do stuff'` .I tried these so far.

```
while True:
  kk = cv2.waitKey(1)
  if kk == ord('s'):
    # Do stuff
    input("Press any key to continue")
    # Do more stuff
```

And

```
while True:
  kk = cv2.waitKey(1)
  if kk == ord('s'):
    # Do stuff
    print("Press c to continue")
    if kk == ord('c'):
      # Do more stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using input, you could use cv2.waitKey once more.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("D://Code//01.Python//yolov5//runs//detect//exp8//3.jpg")
cv2.imshow("name", img)
kk = cv2.waitKey(0)
if kk == ord('s'):
    print("Do stuff")
    tmp = cv2.waitKey(0)
    print("Do More Stuff")
```

[image]